# Segmentation fault on a null struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

This is for a class assignment. I just need to read words from an input file into tree nodes, and catalog them by frequency. Unfortunately, I'm getting a segfault. I've run the program through gdb, and I've found that the fault occurs during the *second pass* through addtree. It hits `strcmp(w, p->word)` and faults.

Upon further investigation, it looks like this is because `p->word` has a value of `0x0`, as if the string never got copied into it. Is there something really simple that I'm missing? I'll try to include only the offending and related bits of code here. (edit: looks like that was everything except `treeprint`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXWORD 100

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
void treeprint(struct tnode *);
int getword(char *, int);
char *strdup(const char *);

struct tnode
{
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
};

main()
{
    struct tnode *root;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    root = NULL;
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF) {
       if (isalpha(word[0])) {
         root = addtree(root, word);
       }
    }

    treeprint(root);

    return 0;
}

int getword(char *word, int lim)
{
    char *w = word;
    int c;

    while (isspace(c = getch())) {}
    if (c != EOF)
    {
        *w++ = c;
    }

    if (!isalpha(c))
    {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }

    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch()))
        {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    }

    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}

struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

char *strdup(const char *s)
{
    char *p;

    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1);

    if (p == NULL)
        strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w)
{
    int cond;

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        p = talloc();
        p->word = strdup(w);
        p->count = 1;

        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    }
    else if ((cond = strcmp(w, p->word)) == 0)
        p->count++;
    else if (cond < 0)
        p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
    else
        p->right = addtree(p->right, w);

    return p;
}

void treeprint(struct tnode *p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        treeprint(p->left);
        printf("%4d %s\n", p->count, p->word);
        treeprint(p->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: A structure instance cannot be null in C FYI. Null is relevant only to pointer types.

Comment: So you know, strdup is part of string.h, you didn't have to write it yourself.

Comment: `if (p == NULL)
        strcpy(p, s);` -->> `if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p, s);` (but there are more errors)

Comment: Amazing. It's running now. If it weren't for you guys, I'd still be banging my head on the wall over mixed-up `=`s, `==`s, and `!=`s. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (p = NULL)
```

should be

```
if (p == NULL)
```

in `strdup`

Comment: Looks like ouah's post disappeared as I was commenting on it....
At the risk of embarrassing myself, is initialization completely necessary? When I look at it, it seems perfectly logical to me. Set it to `NULL`, then call `addtree`. If it's `NULL`, allocate the proper memory for it.
I've also corrected the issue in `strdup` and it runs, but it just prints out a (thankfully finite) series of 1. No words ever get added, and no frequencies go above 1. Any insight? I'll attach the `treeprint` function above for reference.